# GitLab Omnibus Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, ruby, gitlab

I am trying to build GitLab from the Omnibus project in my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit following [this link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md)

After issuing `sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-bundler` I downloaded the source from [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/)  and after exrtaction I made a `bundle install --binstubs`

I got the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:8:in `require': no
such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)   from
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:8     from
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:11:in `require'    from
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:11     from /usr/bin/bundle:4:in
`require'   from /usr/bin/bundle:4
```

What's my problem?

Comment: Is that the full error output you see after running the `bundle` command? What Ruby version are you running? The instructions say that you need 1.9+, but Ubuntu 12.04 comes with 1.8.7. Make sure you follow instructions for Ubuntu 12.04 or set up a [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to install a newer Ruby version locally.

Comment: yes sir, that's it

Comment: @gertvdijk You are right I upgraded ruby to v1.9 and it wokrs. You can put your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upgrade your ruby version from 1.8.* to 1.9.*. To do that you can do it using RVM or without.

**Method1:** [source](http://leonard.io/blog/2012/05/installing-ruby-1-9-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pengolin/)
Installing Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin (without RVM)

If you want to make Ruby 1.9 the default do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install the packages

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev rubygems1.9.1 irb1.9.1 ri1.9.1 rdoc1.9.1 build-essential libopenssl-ruby1.9.1 libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Make 1.9.* default

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 400 \
             --slave   /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz ruby.1.gz \
                            /usr/share/man/man1/ruby1.9.1.1.gz \
            --slave   /usr/bin/ri ri /usr/bin/ri1.9.1 \
            --slave   /usr/bin/irb irb /usr/bin/irb1.9.1 \
            --slave   /usr/bin/rdoc rdoc /usr/bin/rdoc1.9.1
```

choose your interpreter
changes symlinks for /usr/bin/ruby , /usr/bin/gem /usr/bin/irb, /usr/bin/ri and man (1) ruby

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
sudo update-alternatives --config gem
```

Now try

```
ruby --version
```

**Method2:**[source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm)
Install Ruby on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) with RVM

*Step One— Install Ruby with RVM*

first update your sources lits

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Once that's done, we can start installing RVM, Ruby Version Manager.

If you do not have curl on your system, you can start by installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

To install RVM, open terminal and type in this command:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

After it is done installing, load RVM. You may first need to exit out of your shell session and start up a new one.

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

In order to work, RVM has some of its own dependancies that need to be installed. To automatically install them:

```
rvm requirements
```

You may need to enter your root password to allow the installation of these dependencies.
On occasion the zlib package may be reported as missing. The RVM page describes the issue and the solution in greater detail here.

*Step Two—Install Ruby*

Once you are using RVM, installing Ruby is easy.

```
rvm install ruby
```

The latest ruby is now installed. However, since we accessed it through a program that has a variety of Ruby versions, we need to tell the system to use the version we just installed by default.

```
rvm use ruby --default
```

Comment: You are simply **Awesome**